# SQL Query fails in Java but works outside

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a simple SQL query. It works fine if I use it in SequelPro but when I try to use the query in a Java statement if fails.

The query is operating on a simple table that only has two fields, idpolari and word. I originally structured the query as `SELECT * FROM polari` when this did not work I tried naming the specific fields. Have tried executing the query in SequelPro and against the database and it works fine. It also works from the command line. Just not working in Java.

I am working in Netbeans running MySQL on an IMac.

```
sql = "SELECT idpolari, word FROM polari";

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

ResultSet res1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

I would have expected the full contents fo the polari table, what I get is this error message:

> INFO: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1 SELECT idpolari, word FROM polari

Comment: are you sure that you are selecting from the correct table and database?

Comment: The error would suggest you may have invisible characters in that line. Delete the entire string and manually type it in again.

Comment: That is what I suspected. I have deleted the line and retyped it from scratch again. No difference in the result. Works fine if I cut and paste it into my sql editor in SequalPro or MySQLWorkbench.